# Volley long HTTPS Request never responsed

Tags: java, android, https, android-volley, response

I've created a volley request to receive *HTTPS* backend.

```java
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(uiCallback.getContext(),
    new SSLVerification().getHurlStack(uiCallback.getContext()));

JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
    requestUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    ...
}
req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(3_600_000, 0, 0));

queue.add(req);
```

In the manifest, I have added the Internet permission as follows:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Everything works fine with requests that take only a short while.

But if the response comes over 3 minutes after the request, then the application receives nothing.

On the backend, I've set a breakpoint. After 3 minutes, I've let backend to send a response to the app, but there nothing comes. No success, no error, just nothing.

If I make an *HTTP* request without `SSLVerification`, then I receive a response also after 6 minutes. Instead, *HTTPS* requests longer than 3 minutes just don't want to work.

Change `RetryPolicy` to make many requests it's just a workaround and it's not an option.

Comment: Please try cache strategy.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781244/android-volley-jsonobjectrequest-caching/16852314. I am not sure but It can be helpful.

Comment: Try the api in HTTPS using Postman, see if you get any response there.  See the logs using onErrorResponse in volley too.

Comment: this is the case. with postman https works also by 5 minutes. In **Volley** comes after 3 minutes **nothing**

Answer (score 4):

The response is taking too long to be received in the device and thus the `Volley` is having a `TimeoutError`. You need to modify the default timeout value like the following before sending a request to your server.

```
req.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {
    @Override
    public int getCurrentTimeout() {
        return 360000;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
        return 5000;
    }

    @Override
    public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {

    }
});

queue.add(req);
```

Comment: I have already set `req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(3_600_000, 0, 0));` the first value is `Timeout`, that i set to **1 hour**. But self after 3 Minutes there comes nothing back

Comment: Three minutes is a long time. Are you sure that the context did not go out of scope at that time while you might be browsing other activities? What does your logcat say? Does your code prints any error or verbose message which is unusual? Please post your logcat if that does. And btw, did you try setting up the timeout like the way I have suggested? Its actually working for me for a long wait.

Comment: while the request is view blocked. I see ProgressBar. If i set the url to **HTTP** instead **HTTPS** then response works also after 6 minutes. By **HTTPS** there comes in logback **nothing** back. Your solution i have not tryed yet.

Comment: Please try with the solution first and let me know if you see anything unusual in the logcat. If there is anything, please post it here.

Comment: Still not working. No response is coming. Logs are empty

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(90000, 1, 1f));
```

Comment: This would send same request second time. Backend does not support such type of processing.

Answer (score 0):

*If I make an HTTP request without SSLVerification, then I receive a response also after 6 minutes. Instead, HTTPS requests longer than 3 minutes just don't want to work.*

Can this indicate if your server is timing out?

[Occasionally, Volley fails to return a response from the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47499490/occasionally-volley-fails-to-return-a-response-from-the-server)

Comment: server sends the answer also after 6 minutes by HTTPS, but volley don't receive it.